# Print a webpage (html file) from Python

Tags: python, printing, printers

The question may seem obvious, however, I didn't find the answer.
I'm just trying to send an html local page (not the source) from Python to the printer.

The code:

```
NomFichier = 'test.html'
Fichier = open(NomFichier,'w')      
Fichier.write(doc.getvalue())
time.sleep(1)

printer = os.popen('lpr','w')
printer.write(Fichier)
printer.close()
Fichier.close()
```

The error message I get:

> TypeError: expected a character buffer object lpr : No file in the
>   printer request.

Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You want to print "not the source", i.e. you want to render it?

Comment: Yes, render the html source as sort to print it as a webpage

Comment: That will be quite a lot of work. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587637/light-weight-renderer-html-with-css-in-python) for rendering in the first place, but no idea how to print that...

Comment: I guess I'll have to manage this with the shell script then...

Comment: That won't get you around the problem of having to render HTML to print it.